# Property of renewal point processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, queueing-theory

> For a renewal process where $f(t)$ is the number of arrivals in time $t$ and $S_k$ is the  $k^{th}$ time of arrival, how can we show:

$$f(\alpha S_k)/k \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}}\alpha $$

> as $k \to \infty$, where $0<\alpha<1 $, and $f(t)$ and $S_k$ belong to two separate renewal process of the same type with the same parameters?

We know $S_k/k\xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} \overline{X}$ and $f(t)/t \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} 1/\overline{X}$, where $\overline{X}$ is the mean between two occurrence. How can I merge these two to obtain the above?

Answer (score 0):

When combined with what you already know, doesn't
$$
{f(\alpha S_k)\over k} = {f(\alpha S_k)\over\alpha S_k}\cdot{S_k\over k}\cdot\alpha
$$
do the trick?

Comment: Can you provide me next steps?

Comment: You've already stated the limit of $S_k/k$ as $k\to\infty$. What is the limit of $f(\alpha S_k)/\alpha S_k$ as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: We have to prove two things to use the above's equation. First, $A_n \xrightarrow{a.s}A$ and $B_n \xrightarrow{a.s}B$ , then $A_n B_n\xrightarrow{a.s}A B$ . (This is a property, but I don't know where I can find it in the books). Second, we have to prove $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{f(\alpha S_k)}{\alpha k} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{f(t)}{t}$. Why is this true?

Comment: @Su20200 Please note that you wish to use that $\lim_{k \to \infty} = \frac{f(\alpha S_k)}{\alpha S_k} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{f(t)}{t}$, rather than what you wrote.